# How to insert a command button relative to a cell (value)?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a VBA code to put this button lets say two cells (to the right) away from a cell in the sheet called "hello". Here's the command button code:

```
Set objBtn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
    , DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=480, Top:=200, Width:=90, Height:= _
     30)
objBtn.Name = "button1"
```

I don't want to use the cell location as reference, instead the cell value which is "hello". So maybe first I want to look for the value and then insert the command button relative to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the way to do it, e.g.

```
Sub x()

Dim objBtn As OLEObject, r As Range

Set r = Cells.Find("hello") 'should specify more parameters than this
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    Set objBtn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, _
                 DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=r.Offset(, 2).Left, Top:=r.Top, Width:=90, Height:=30)
    objBtn.Name = "button1"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks brilliant. I'm gonna mark this answer as solution tomorrow after testing it with the whole code. Much appreciated.

Comment: do u think i could bring it 2 cells up using Top:=r.(, 2)? because I tried that and it goes all the way up instead of just 2 cells.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - are you referring to the height? You can play around with all four settings.

Comment: the code works fine when I try for moving the button two cells to the right, but what if I want to move it two cells up? I tried to play around with Top and Left but couldn't get it done.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer - have you worked it out? `top=r.offset(-2).top`

Comment: Yes, I was missing .top at the end when I tried to modify it to bring the button up. It works perfectly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

'You can fixe a button to a specific cell here to cell A1

```
Dim rngcbn1 As Range
 Set rngcbn1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
 With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CommandButton1")
        .Top = rngcbn1.Top
        .Left = rngcbn1.Left
        .Width = rngcbn1.Width
        .Height = rngcbn1.RowHeight
 End With
```